# Is serverfault the right forum for the below question

Tags: discussion

What is the performance impact of SSL with openJDK 8? I know there's no hard and fast answer to this, but I am looking for performance under the following scenario.

1. Performance of network I/O for SSL vs non-SSL connections.
2. Multiple long running network connections.
3. I'm **not** looking for the latency impact of the SSL handshake.
4. **I am** looking for the performance impact (latency) of the symmetric encryption/decryption on the wire.

I'm interested in these results for *OpenJDK 8.* Preferably for a range of ciphers that are supported by the JDK.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that "just run the tests yourself" is the right approach for that question.  I doubt that there are many people who have run those specific tests in an environment as close to yours as to make it worthwhile to use the results, and the chances of your finding them are... remote.  Certainly, however, it is not on-topic for ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

From a first impression, this seems more like a dev question, so it would be more of a topic for SO (but check their help center before!).

Comment: I had earlier asked the same question there, but it was downvoted and closed as being off topic. :(

Comment: It doesn't look like dev to me, but I am also having trouble seeing the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like dev to me, but I am also having trouble seeing the point of the question. What is the business purpose for this? The latency of encryption and decryption is minuscule on modern hardware with AES acceleration (e.g. Intel CPUs from the last decade). Nobody even attempts to measure this anymore as it hasn't been a significant operational concern for a long time.

Comment: That "pointless" latency is exactly what I need to measure. I too, don't see the point of it. But I need to share my results for the same.